# Simplesamlphp 2.0.6 wso2 entityID

Tags: php, wso2, single-sign-on, simplesamlphp

I receive this error when I try test in simplesamlphp to wso2 identify server:

Caused by: SimpleSAML\Assert\AssertionFailedException: 'simple' is not a valid RFC3986 compliant URI

The code of authsources.php is:

```
'wso2-sp' => array(  

        'saml:SP',  
          
        
        'entityID' => 'simple',  
        
       
        'idp' => 'https://localhost:9443/samlsso',  
        
  
        'discoURL' => NULL,  
        
        ),
```

And the code of metadata saml20-idp-remote.php is:

```
$metadata['https://localhost:9443/samlsso'] = array(  

    'name' => array(  

    'en' =>  'WSO2 IS',  

    'no' =>  'WSO2 IS',  

),  

    'description'   =>  'Login with WSO2 IS SAML2 IdP.',  

    'SingleSignOnService'  =>  'https://localhost:9443/samlsso',  

    'SingleLogoutService'  => 'https://localhost:9443/samlsso',  

    'certFingerprint'      => '6bf8e136eb36d4a56ea05c7ae4b9a45b63bf975d'  

);
```

The data in my wso2 identity server is correct, why am I getting this error? (Caused by: SimpleSAML\Assert\AssertionFailedException: 'simple' is not a valid RFC3986 compliant URI).

Thanks for help.